# Delete all but greatest-n-per-group in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

If I have two Postgres tables, say

```
CREATE TABLE store (
    id text,
    name text
)

CREATE TABLE product (
    store_id text,
    id text,
    created_at timestamp
)
```

I know I can get a table with the newest product with

```
SELECT product.*
FROM store JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ON (store_id)
                 FROM product ORDER BY store_id, created_at DESC)
           AS newest_product_by_store
ON newest_product_by_store.store_id = store.id
```

How, then, would I do a DELETE USING that deletes every product not in `newest_product_by_store`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bullet proof way :

```
delete from product
where id not in (
    select a.id
    from (
        select p.id
        from product p
        inner join (
            select store_id, max(created_at)
            from product
            group by store_id
            ) b
            on p.store_id = b.store_id
                and p.created_at = b.created_at
        ) a
    )
```

---

Assuming your `ID` are auto-increment and you can't insert `created_at` back in time :

```
delete from product 
where id not in (
  select a.id 
  from (
    select max(id) as id
    from product 
    group by store_id
    ) a
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method:

```
delete from product p
    using (SELECT DISTINCT ON (store_id) p.*
          FROM product p
          ORDER BY store_id, created_at DESC
         ) ps
    where p.store_id = ps.store_id and p.created_at < ps.created_at;
```

This would often be written without the subquery:

```
delete from product p
    where p.created_at < (select max(p2.created_at) from product p2 where p2.store_id = p.store_id);
```